# Fast file encryption in android

Tags: android, file, encryption

Hi i am creating a sample to lock file or folder in android. I have a issue when i encrypt or decrypt large size (more than 1 GB) file  it takes too much time.
Please help me to encrypt and decrypt file fastly.
Here i am attaching code which i am using on below

```
 if (!isEncrypted) {
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
                        // This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by another stream.
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + ".abcd");

                        // Length is 16 byte
                        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("abcdefghijklmnop".getBytes(), "AES");
                        // Create cipher
                        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
                        // Wrap the output stream
                        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
                        // Write bytes
                        int b;
                        byte[] d = new byte[1024];
                        try {
                            while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
                                cos.write(d, 0, b);
                            }

                            // Flush and close streams.
                            cos.flush();
                            cos.close();
                            fis.close();
                            new File(path).deleteOnExit();
                            isEncrypted = true;
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    btnEncrypt.setText("Decrypt Path");
                                    deleteMyFile(path);
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path + ".abcd");

                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("abcdefghijklmnop".getBytes(), "AES");
                        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
                        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
                        int b;
                        byte[] d = new byte[1024];


                        while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
                            fos.write(d, 0, b);
                        }
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        cis.close();
                        isEncrypted = false;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                deleteMyFile(path + ".abcd");
                                btnEncrypt.setText("Encrypt Path");
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressDialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: How long is "too much time"?  Also, the encryption code you are using has a number of weaknesses and insecurities.  I wouldn't use it in production code.

Comment: Thanks Luke Park to read my question. It takes 2 minutes , i want to do it within second.Is it possible to lock large file within second ? please help

Comment: "Is it possible to lock large file within second ?" -- that depends. Are you building your own hardware? If so, you are welcome to try to build it with high-end components to try to achieve that speed. On ordinary Android hardware, you cannot *write* 1GB in a second, ignoring any encryption/decryption. On some hardware, I'd be impressed if you could write 1 GB in a minute.

Comment: On my PC, which (I believe) has a chip capable of hardware-accelerated AES, encrypting a ~1GB file takes 20.2 seconds.  The average mobile phone (and hopefully not high end ones either!) is nowhere near as fast as my desktop.  It simply is not possible.  Additionally, you aren't "locking" a file, you're encrypting it.

Comment: Is any way to lock folder without encrypt of its file of folder? I want to lock folder and i don't want to encrypt file but i could't get any way to lock folder.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no way to do it faster because of read/write memory speed at least.If you just read or write 1 GB file, it would take ~50 seconds for 20 mbytes/sec speed. So you basically have to 1) read file: 50 sec. 2) encrypt file: 30 sec. 3) write file: 50 sec. So 130 sec. in total.

Comment: Is any way lock folder within second without encryption and decryption ? please help

Comment: There is no way to "lock" a folder, no.  You should also stop saying "please help" so much.  It can be considered somewhat rude.

Comment: ok Luke Park your suggestion is valuable for me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found a way to do this. But, here is how I do it.

I realized that writing our own AES classes in java Or C is not recommendable way if you are especially just focused on the end result. Java is pretty slow in comparison with C, but in java you can use multithreading whereas in C you can't. Of course there are aes c programs which do a better job. But using them is difficult. You said you want to encrypt 1GB file under a minute. So, do this.

Install Userland Or Termux and install openssl. Next cd to your file storage location and try aes encrypt command. To automate it, write a bash script and run it. Openssl can easily do 23 MBps to 68 MBps.